# jQuery ajax callback json parsing issue

Tags: json, jquery, github

I'm working with Github API V3

I'm using following code to make ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/gists',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "public": true,
        "files": {
            "sample.html": {
                "content": 'html content'
            }           
        }, 
    }),
    success:function(response){
        alert(response.id);
    }
});
```

I have to stringify data as Github API returns Error 400! if i don't. With above example, Github API does response as I expect.

I'm having issue with callback parsing though. Above code works with webkit & opera but firefox fails with success function. I have to modify code as below to get work in firefox.

```
success:function(response){
    alert(JSON.parse(response).id);
}
```

But then Webkit & Opera fails with success response with above modified code.

What is correct way to get success callback across all browser ? What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `dataType: 'json',` property to your ajax call check if it works..like the one below

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```