# Creating a Git Hub Repositories using Ajax JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, github

I am trying to create a *GitHub* repository using *AJAX from JQuery*, but it is not working, my code is here:

```
    $.ajax({

    url: "https://api.github.com/my-user/repos",
    headers: { 'Authorization' : 'token my-token' },
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
      "name": "new-repos",
      "description" : "New-repos",
      "auto_init": true, 
      "private": false,

    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
    var html_content_header = "";
    var obj_header=request.getAllResponseHeaders();

     $('#header').html(JSON.stringify(request.getAllResponseHeaders()));


var html_content_text = "";
     Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(
  function (val, idx, array) {
    html_content_text=html_content_text+val + ' -> ' + data[val]+ '<br>';
  }
);
     $('#text').html(html_content_text);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {

  alert(xhr.status);
}
});
```

It shows this error in console:

> POST https://api.github.com/my-user/repos 404 (Not Found)

And in my error alert:

> 404

I followed the guide of getting started  by *GitHub* https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/, but instead of using *CURL*, i was using *AJAX from JQuery*.

Everything was going smoothly, until i tried creating a new repository.
I have verified that my token has the correct scopes.

I kind of guess that it does not found the *URL*.

Is there some kind of limitation using *AJAX from JQuery* and *GitHub*?

Am i writing wrong the *URL*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitHub API for creating a repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) is

```
POST /user/repos
```

Not "`my-user/repo`"

See "[GitHub API AJAX POST returning 422](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601971/6309)" for a full example: no trailing '`,`' in `data`, and use `data: JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/issues',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'token MY_PERSONAL_TOKEN'
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "title": "Found a bug",
        "description": "Bug description"
      }),
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
```

Comment: It sends the `POST https://api.github.com/user/repos 400 (Bad Request)` error, meaning that i have send a  invalid   _JSON_ , then is there an error in my _JSON_ ? or in my  _JSON_ format?

Comment: @R.D.S. maybe the final ',' in data. See https://github.com/ammiranda/jqueryajaxhowto/blob/master/apiDocs/docs/index.md

Comment: @R.D.S. How about stringify the data, as in JSON.stringify: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38601971/6309 ? Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/13854752/6309? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/23974430/6309?